# Modify size of nodes and their opacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I am drawing bipartite graphs using Tikz and I do not seem to make the nodes smaller (you can see in the code that I specified different sizes for nodes) or to make them seem opaque/2D. If you look at the the example, they seem to be 3D.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
                petri,%
                topaths}%
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \SetVertexNoLabel
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style ={shape = circle, ball color = black, draw, opacity=1, minimum size = 4pt, fill=black}}
  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{A}
  \Vertex[x=2,y=2]{B}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=1.5]{C}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{D}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style ={shape = circle, ball color = white, minimum size = 2pt, draw}}
  \Vertex[x=0,y=2]{E} 
  \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{G}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=0.5]{H}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=2]{I}
  \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[]
  \Edge(A)(G)
  \Edge(A)(E)
  \Edge(B)(E)
  \Edge(B)(G)
  \Edge(B)(I)
  \Edge(C)(I)
  \Edge(C)(H)
  \Edge(D)(H)
  \Edge(D)(G)
  \Edge(D)(I)
  \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend right]
  \Edge(A)(E)
  \Edge(C)(H)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `inner sep` to zero and then define `minimum size of vertex to desired value. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, transform shape]
  \SetVertexNoLabel
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, ball color=black, draw,
                               opacity=0.8, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt}}
  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{A}
  \Vertex[x=2,y=2]{B}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=1.5]{C}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{D}

\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, ball color = white, draw,
                               minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt}}
  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{A} % it override first definition of node A
  \Vertex[x=0,y=2]{E}
  \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{G}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=0.5]{H}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=2]{I}
  \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[]
  \Edge(A)(G)
  \Edge(A)(E)
  \Edge(B)(E)
  \Edge(B)(G)
  \Edge(B)(I)
  \Edge(C)(I)
  \Edge(C)(H)
  \Edge(D)(H)
  \Edge(D)(G)
  \Edge(D)(I)
  \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend right]
  \Edge(A)(E)
  \Edge(C)(H)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding `opacity` is not clear (to me) what you like to obtain. If you like to have some transparencies, then you need to set `opacity` smaller than 1 (in MWE I set it to `opacity=0.8`).

Comment: the `\[ ` was caused by image around the code block

Comment: I was not able to explain what I wanted regarding opacity. If you look at the black vertices they have a white shade, like they are 3D balls rather than circles in the plane. I would like to change that.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `scale=0.5,opacity=0.5` you get nodes of half the original size which are 50% transparent.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
                petri,%
                topaths}%
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \SetVertexNoLabel
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style ={shape = circle, ball color = black, draw, opacity=1, minimum size = 4pt, fill=black}}
  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{A}
  \Vertex[x=2,y=2]{B}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=1.5]{C}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{D}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style ={shape = circle, ball color = white,
scale=0.5,opacity=0.5, draw}}
  \Vertex[x=0,y=2]{E} 
  \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{G}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=0.5]{H}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=2]{I}
  \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[]
  \Edge(A)(G)
  \Edge(A)(E)
  \Edge(B)(E)
  \Edge(B)(G)
  \Edge(B)(I)
  \Edge(C)(I)
  \Edge(C)(H)
  \Edge(D)(H)
  \Edge(D)(G)
  \Edge(D)(I)
  \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[bend right]
  \Edge(A)(E)
  \Edge(C)(H)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]